# What is the plural form of regex?

Tags: abbreviations, irregular-plurals

As the title says, what is the correct plural form of **regex**?

To my knowledge, **regex** is an abbreviation for **regular expression**.
I see that [some sources](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/regex.html) suggest **regexes** and **regexen** are both correct. The latter plural form sounds maybe German?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, Alireza. This is general reference. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) has << The phrase _regular expressions_, and consequently, _regexes_, is often used to mean the specific, standard textual syntax (distinct from the mathematical notation described below) for representing patterns for matching text. >> Wikipedia is a better recognised source than the one you link to. // Appearance in the OED of 'regex' and 'regexes' would certainly confirm wordness, but I think you can use them safely in all but the most formal registers.

Comment: VTC. Sorry, I voted to leave open by mistake.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I prefer "regices" like "index -> indices" or "vortex -> vortices".

Comment: If you've used more than one of them, you'll know that the plural of "regex" is "regrets."

Comment: @cjs this made my day and is the best answer to the question in my subjective opinion, thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is domain-specific jargon (the domain being Information Technology), rather than standard English, and thus may not conform to the rules. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regex) and [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-plural-form-of-regexp) both give *regexes* or *regexps*; while I don't find *regexen* unlikely, I've not actually seen/heard it used, and it would not come to mind immediately for me.

(*You are correct that it is an abbreviation/shorthand for **regular expression***)

Comment: I've never seen it either, but I wouldn't put it past programmers to use it; as well as a third-declension Latin plural _regeges_.

Comment: Actually, the plural of "regex" is "regrets" (https://twitter.com/ifosteve/status/1190348262500421634)

Comment: @Kankaristo - Been there, done that, tossed the T-shirt on a bonfire. See similar comment on the question itself (from cjs).

Comment: I happened to see "regexen" on a StackOverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828236/how-to-make-this-sed-script-faster). I wondered why they were conjugating it like that, so found this post.

Comment: @QZ my guess is a copy of "ox(en)".
(I found this post searching if anyone thought about regices)